# Como usar la url con tildes en python ya que al consultar me da error con los caracteres

Tags: python-3.x, ascii

Al querer consultar con Python una url me da el error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf3' in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)`

¿Qué debería agregar a mi código para poder consultar sin problemas?

```
from PIL import Image
url='https://tpcgroup-int.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/TPC-Chile_-obligación-de-declaraciónes-de-p 
recios-de-transferencia-.png'
image = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como en cualquier petición, la URL tiene que ir URL-encoded para que pueda ser resuelta correctamente. No sólo en python; siempre que hagas una petición de una URL.

En la librería urllib, está disponible quote (y unquote para el proceso contrario)

```
from PIL import Image
url = 'https://tpcgroup-int.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/TPC-Chile_-obligación-de-declaraciónes-de-p 
recios-de-transferencia-.png'
encodedUrl = urllib.parse.quote(url, safe=':')
image = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(encodedUrl))
```

Comment: Hola alfabravo, ahora me da el siguiente error:unknown url type: 'https%3A//tpcgroup-int.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/TPC-Chile_-obligaci%C3%B3n-de-declaraci%C3%B3nes-de-precios-de-transferencia-.png'

Comment: @ARLESAGUSTINTABOADASANCHEZ edité la respuesta porque está escapando los dos puntos y necesitamos que los mantenga (así que usamos el parámetro safe para que no los escape)

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo ya me di cuenta me da error por esta https%3A, te agradezco ahora puedo avanzar con mi script. Saludos estimado

Comment: Con gusto siempre! :)